# How to solve the "retrieve_values" problem

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm working on this problem:

> Write a method retrieve_values that takes in two hashes and a key. The method should return an array containing the values from the two hashes that correspond with the given key.

```
def retrieve_values(hash1, hash2, key)
  

end


dog1 = {"name"=>"Fido", "color"=>"brown"}
dog2 = {"name"=>"Spot", "color"=> "white"}
print retrieve_values(dog1, dog2, "name") #=> ["Fido", "Spot"]
puts
print retrieve_values(dog1, dog2, "color") #=> ["brown", "white"]
puts
```

I came up with a working solution:

```
def retrieve_values(hash1, hash2, key)
  arr = []
  hash1.each { |key| } && hash2.each { |key| }
    if key == "name"
      arr << hash1["name"] && arr << hash2["name"] 
    elsif key == "color"
      arr << hash1["color"] && arr << hash2["color"]
    end
  return arr
end
```

I then looked at the 'official' solution:

```
def retrieve_values(hash1, hash2, key)
  val1 = hash1[key]
  val2 = hash2[key]
  return [val1, val2]
end
```

What is wrong with my code? Or is it an acceptable "different" approach?

Comment: Technically, nothing is wrong.  It satisfies the criteria.  Do you understand what is going on in the official solution?

Comment: Yes, I do, thank you :)

Comment: I'd highly recommend reading all of "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)".

Comment: @theTinMan I actually looked for a 'style guide' like this before posting but didn't manage to find it. I will read this, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line with `hash1.each { |key| } && hash2.each { |key| }` just does nothing it is not needed even in your solution.

This part a bit difficult to read `arr << hash1["name"] && arr << hash2["name"]`. It mutates the array two times in one line, this kind of style could lead to bugs.
Also, your code sticks only to two keys `name` and `color`:

```
dog1 = {"name"=>"Fido", "color"=>"brown", "age" => 1}
dog2 = {"name"=>"Spot", "color"=> "white", "age" => 2}
> retrieve_values(dog1, dog2, "age") 
 => []
```

The official solution will return `[1, 2]`.

You don't need here to explicitly use `return` keyword, any block of code returns the last evaluated expression. But it is a matter of style guide.

It is possible to simplify even the official solution:

```
def retrieve_values(hash1, hash2, key)
  [hash1[key], hash2[key]]
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Super helpful :)